# FTP / SFTP to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

OK, I'm having issues with connecting to the AWS server.

I want to use FTP or SFTP. SFTP is preferred, but right now I don't care.
The AWS is **Windows** running Filezilla Server (using ports 30000-35000). The security ports have been opened (21-22, 30000-35000)
I'm using Filezilla Client on Windows 7 (using ports 30000-35000).
I have converted the pem file to use in Filezilla.
I have followed all the instructions I could find in a google search.
I have tried both ec2-user & administrator as the username, and left the password blank.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

However, the Filezilla Server log says:

```
(000415)6/26/2014 19:21:10 PM - (not logged in) (130.88.148.85)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000415)6/26/2014 19:21:10 PM - (not logged in) (130.88.148.85)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.45 beta
(000415)6/26/2014 19:21:10 PM - (not logged in) (130.88.148.85)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000415)6/26/2014 19:21:10 PM - (not logged in) (130.88.148.85)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000415)6/26/2014 19:21:10 PM - (not logged in) (130.88.148.85)> disconnected.
```

Any help here?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the PEM file for your EC2 instance when your created it? This is what you would use to connect via SSH or FTP. A pem file can only be downloaded once, the first time its created so put it in a safe place. To ssh to your ec2 instance you would run the following from a terminal or ssh client

Amazon Linux

```
ssh -i myKey.pem ec2-user@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.com
```

Ubuntu

```
ssh -i myKey.pem ubuntu@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.com
```

Also make sure that your security group is allowing the port for your FTP or SSH client. To start of you can just set your security group to allow 0.0.0.0/0 and adjust it later.

I do not use an FTP client. I instead use the linux command scp, secure copy.

Like this...

To copy from local to server

```
scp -i myKey.pem ~/myFile.txt ec2-user@ec2-XXX.com:/home/ec2-user/
```

To copy from server to local

```
scp -i myKey.pem ec2-user@ec2-XXX.com:/home/ec2-user/myFile.txt ./
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the pem file created when I set up the ec2. Also, I'm running Windows. Plus I want the GUI interface. I don't care for command lines.

Comment: I think the command line is the most efficient way to do this. The more you get into Amazon the more things you will have to do with command line, so Cygwin becomes my Windows tool of choice. Did you get your FTP working?

Comment: The command line might be OK for 1 file. Maybe 2. But when you start getting into a LOT of files, a GUI interface can't be beat. Especially when it has a lot of built-in overwrite rules. I got plain FTP working. I'll worry about a secure FTP later. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with using "*", to handle multi files? GUI is never going to give you the customization you could get from writing your own bash script. I understand the GUI is easy to use for novice users, but CLI/scripts/programs will always beat the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a connection issue instead of a permissions issue. Yes, the port may be open, but is the SSH *system service* running on the remote Windows instance (I don't recall the default settings for Windows in EC2)?

Comment: Never checked. I got plain FTP working. I'll worry about a secure FTP later. Thanks.